# Unable to access HBase database (which is running on secured cluster) from Eclipse?

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-spark-sql, kerberos, hbase-client

Trying to connect to `HBase database` from Eclipse Scala program in `Windows`.

Cluster is `secured using Kerberos` Authentication, so its not connecting to the Hbase database.

Every time we are creating the jar file and running in the cluster. but this is not useful for development and debug.

How do i set the `hbase-site.xml` in classpath?

I downloaded `*site.xml` files tried adding the `hbase-site.xml, core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml` as `source` folder and tried adding this files as external class folder from the project build path, but nothing is working. How do i make this working?

Is there anyway we can set the `hbase-site.xml` in sqlContext, since i am using sqlContext to read the Hbase tables using HortonWorks connector.

**Error log is:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.RegionResource.init(HBaseResources.scala:93)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.liftedTree1$1(HBaseResources.scala:57)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.acquire(HBaseResources.scala:54)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.RegionResource.acquire(HBaseResources.scala:88)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.releaseOnException(HBaseResources.scala:74)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.RegionResource.releaseOnException(HBaseResources.scala:88)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.RegionResource.<init>(HBaseResources.scala:108)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD.getPartitions(HBaseTableScan.scala:60)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:190)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:319)
       at scb.HBaseBroadcast$.main(HBaseBroadcast.scala:106)
       at scb.HBaseBroadcast.main(HBaseBroadcast.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
       ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy()Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/FailoverProxyProvider$ProxyInfo;
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.<init>(RetryInvocationHandler.java:73)
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.<init>(RetryInvocationHandler.java:64)
       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:147)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:510)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:453)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:104)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:241)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:879)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635)
       ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a hadoop-dfs conflict.  Please check the version on the server vs. the one on your development path.

Comment: Thanks,let me check that, i haven't added hadoop as separate dependency, i just configured Spark 1.6.1 , which is getting all the dependencies related to the 1.6.1 version, in the Cluster we are using HDP 2.4.2, which is using Spark 1.6.1 version, i will verify the both Hadoop version.. thanks..

Comment: Shankar, we have this problem continuously at Splice Machine.  We have just moved up to Spark 2.0 which is a little bit better.  If you have more problems (which I suspect you will), respond to this thread.  The usual problems for us are Guava, Jackson, and Servlet-api conflicts.  Good Luck!

Comment: Yours is not Kerberos authentication failed error. AFAIK Its not able to connect because of jar file mismatch. I  faced same issue long ago type  ` hbase classpath ` in cluster to  see the jar files present at cluster side and same jar version of jar files needs to be present at windows eclipse .classpath.

Comment: I did below to configure correctly.. `public static void printClassPathResources() {
        final ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        final URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
        LOG.info("Print All Class path resources under currently running class");
        for (final URL url : urls) {
            LOG.info(url.getFile());
        }

    }` check this code from program from both sides.

Comment: `import java.net.URL
import java.net.URLClassLoader
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    val urls = cl.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader].getURLs
    for (url <- urls) {
      println(url.getFile)
    }
  }
}` scala version since you are using scala